# how to mount .vhdx image in lubuntu

Tags: mount, lubuntu, windows-8, backup

So, I had a hard drive with Windows 8.
The drive started dying, so I made an image backup to an external HDD.
Because it's practically impossible to get an ISO of Windows 8, I installed Lubuntu.

Now I'm restoring the backup and moving my files into Lubuntu, but can't figure out how to mount a .vhdx image.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are examples for a file that is called **myvhdxfile.vhdx** that is mounted to **/mnt/vhdxdrive**

**Example 1.** Where guestmount is inspecting (-i) the disks looking for an operating system and mount filesystems:

1. Install `sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools`
2. Create a mountpoint e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/vhdxdrive`
3. Run `sudo guestmount --add myvhdxfile.vhdx -i --rw /mnt/vhdxdrive`
4. (optional when you are done inspecting the files) To unmount run `sudo guestunmount /mnt/vhdxdrive`

**Example 2.** If you run into the error: **guestmount: no operating system was found on this disk** you can mount individual partitions by following these steps:

1. Run `sudo guestfish --rw -a myvhdxfile.vhdx`
2. Type in `run` and hit enter
3. Type in `list-filesystems` and hit enter and note the path to the partition
4. Type in `exit` and hit enter

The output of the above steps might look like this:

```
><fs> run
><fs> list-filesystems 
/dev/sda2: ntfs
><fs> exit
```

Finally, you can mount the partition `/dev/sda2` by running:

- `sudo guestmount --add myvhdxfile.vhdx --rw /mnt/vhdxdrive -m /dev/sda2`

If you got a different partition path from running the *list-filesystems* command in guestfish than you should replace `/dev/sda2` with this path in the above command.

**Example 3.**
If you want the mounted partition to pup up in files (nautilus) and be able to access it with your personal user account:

1. Create a mountpoint in media `sudo mkdir /media/vhdxdrive`
2. Mount with user permissions `sudo guestmount --add myvhdxfile.vhdx -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o allow_other --rw /media/vhdxdrive -m /dev/sda2`

Change the uid and gid values to the corresponding ids of your user in above command.

Comment: Almost seven years too late but hopefully it'll help someone else!